SEO, CDN - is statically generating thousands of HTML files and removing all JS & WordPress a good approach?
They have bad SEO, and I was just brought in. My recommendation immediately was to remove all JavaScript, WordPress, and other frameworks/plugins/widgets and write a new thing entirely in simple HTML & CSS.
What I'm thinking is a simple content editor [on a subdomain or even offline] for the nontechnical author to use for CRUDing pages and posts, and a handful of simple HTML templates that can be interpolated from the database.
Then ahead-of-time (AoT) thousands of HTML pages are to be generated with folders indicating hierarchy.
This seems like classic 1990s advice I'm giving. Is this correct advice?
